# Impossible to return S_FALSE in HResult

Tags: delphi

In several of my COM object the HResult of a function can be S_OK or S_FALSE, but when I try to call theses function in a client application, I allways get S_OK=0 and never S_FALSE=1.
For example in a ENumVariant you have the Next method or Reset, if I write

```
result:=S_False
```

in the server code, if I test HResult in my client code I allways get 0 (S_OK).

I use XE8. I have made an MCVE.
The code of the server is here:
[enter link description here](http://www.etoiles-a-bleau/transfert/Server.zip)
and the code of the client is here:
[enter link description here](http://www.etoiles-a-bleau/transfert/TestTest.zip)

With the `WriteToTrace` in `Reset` function I can see that `Reset` is called. And in the test program, `Return` is allways=0. It's the same thing if I call `Next` or `Clone` where I have forced `Result:=S_FALSE`.

Comment: This doesn't seem right, surely if you assign something to the result, it should return just that. Can you show the full contents of and how you call such a function which always returns `S_OK`? It sounds like the problem could be a calling convention mis-match. Also, which Delphi version are you using? And on both sides of COM?

Comment: This is nonsense. The line of code you posted would return S_FALSE under all but two circumstances: 1) The function is never called, meaning the line of code is never executed, or 2) something in the code after that line executes is changing Result. Your one line of code out of context is meaningless. Show an actual, compilable app with a function that contains that line of code, and code that calls that function where it does not return S_FALSE. And when I say compilable, I mean code we can copy from your question, compile, and run. Tons of COM controls return S_FALSE from Delphi code.

Comment: Could it be that you have an old .dcu accessible somewhere, and that that is used instead? Change the text of `WriteToTrace`, just to be sure (e.g. `WriteToTrace('This is a new version');`) that the new text is written, and not the old one. If the old text still appears, you are not calling the code you edited. Happened a few times to me, and that can be extremely frustrating.

Comment: This is a real question. I could reproduce this issue with a simple automation object with the interface based off IEnumVARIANT. if I use `CreateOLEObject` I get 0 (S_OK) always. If I use early binding with an imported type library I get 1 (S_FAIL) or whatever I pass as HResult as expected.

Comment: Ok, I am not crazy!! Jasper can you explain a little bit more what you have done? Thanks

Comment: @michastro please post a MCVE. Seems like no-one else seem to think this is even possible.

Comment: Hello, I have made a MCVE wich shows the problem: [link](http://www.etoiles-a-bleau.fr/transfert/Server.zip) . It's the server, and the Reset send the S_FALSE result. Now this small code in a program call the Reset function and the result is allways S_OK: [link](http://www.etoiles-a-bleau.fr/transfert/TestTest.zip)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only solution I found was to import the type library and using early binding.

I post my findings in a hope someone can give a better solution.

I verfied what the OP described. I could reproduce the problem as follows. I created an Automation Object using the wizard and in type library editor I change the ancestor from `IDispath` to `IEnumVARIANT`. For the implementation of `IEnumVARIANT` I only added `S_FALSE` for each of the `HResults`.

When used with an application that imported the type library I would get `S_FALSE` as expected, but once I used `CreateOLEObject` I would get `S_OK` every time.

Here is what I think happens. `IEnumVARIANT` has the calling convention of `stdcall` and that is correct, they return only `HResult`. But it seems that when they are invoked through a dispatch interface the result gets lost and `S_OK` is always returned. I wondered if the `stdcall` is implicitly re-boxed as as a `safecall`, but then again... we get a result, so I scrapped that idea.

Comment: That's very strange!! I have tried too `safecall`, but the problem remained. Perhaps Delphi is not really the best langage to program and use COM objects :-(

Comment: @michastro I don't think you can change the calling convention since its defined in IEnumVARIANT. Please note that your sample was not minimal or easily verifiable, you will get downvoted and many incredulous replies when you do that